# Error using hyperref and tex4ebook

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, tex4ebook

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}
\title{Test}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle  
    \frontmatter    
    \tableofcontents \newpage   
    \mainmatter     
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter{New Chapter}
    I am citing a book \footnote{sample footnote}.


    \backmatter     
\end{document}
```

I get following error message.

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'Hfootnote' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

My `.mk4` file is as follows:

```
Make:htlatex {}
Make:htlatex {}
```

Comment: Your code can not be tested as we don't have the input files. Show a real minimal example.

Comment: Added a simplified code. There is some issue with HFootnote.

Comment: Does the problem actually have anything to do with `biblatex` or can you reproduce the same error without `biblatex`? (If the latter is the case, please simplify your MWE further.)

Comment: The error exists independent of biblatex. As soon as I add \usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}, it gives error.

Comment: If the question has otherwise nothing to do with `biblatex` I recommend you remove the code for the bibliography (and the `biblatex` tag) to streamline the question and provide only the code necessary to reproduce the issue and nothing more.

Comment: code updated. Issue with HFootnote counter.

Comment: Thanks. I retagged the question.

Comment: Further problems have been raised [here]. [here]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507356/hyperlink-does-not-work-properly-with-biblatex-and-tex4ebook

Answer (score 3):

There is a clash between `Memoir`, `Hyperref` and `tex4ht` in a definition of footnotes. The simplest fix is to define the `Hfootnote` counter in `tex4ht`. This can be done in a custom configuration file. Save the following code as `mycfg.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
\ifHy@hyperfootnotes
\newcounter{Hfootnote}
\fi
}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Request the config file using

```
tex4ebook -c mycfg.cfg filename.tex
```

The compilation should run without errors.

Comment: Thanks! this works. However, when a bibliography entry is clicked, it comes back to the first page of the chapter instead of bibliography page.

Comment: @JyotiranjanBeuria I think this is another issue. or did it work before this fix?

Comment: Yes, it worked before this trick. Now with this .cfg file, I am not able to reach an appropriate bibliography page.