# Error in hyperlink with biblatex in tex4ebook compilation

Tags: biblatex, hyperlink, tex4ebook

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[backend = biber,url= false,style=numeric,sorting=none, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}
\title{Test}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle  
    \frontmatter    
    \tableofcontents \newpage   
    \mainmatter     
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{New Chapter}
    \lipsum
    \newpage
    I am citing a book\cite{ABC:2019} that contains \footnote{sample footnote}.
    \printbibliography  
    \backmatter     
\end{document}
```

test.bib file is as follows.

```
@book{ABC:2019,
    author={ABC},
    title={Test},
    publisher={T},
    year={2019}
}
```

I am using tex4ebook for creating epub file. When bib entry is clicked, the first page of chapter opens up instead of bibliography.

.mk4 file is

```
Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
Make:htlatex {}

Make:biber {}

Make:htlatex {}
Make:htlatex {}
```

.cfg file is

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
\ifHy@hyperfootnotes
\newcounter{Hfootnote}
\fi
}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

On the other hand, if I remove `\footnote{}` from "`I am citing a book\cite{ABC:2019} that contains \footnote{sample footnote}`" line, bib entry hyperlink works fine.